# Is there a way to make a matrix without a repeating value?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

```
import random

def main():
values = [
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        ]
for r in range(5):
    for c in range(5):
        rand = random.randint(1, 25)
        if values[r][c] != rand:
            values[r][c] = rand

        

for i in range(5):
    print("\n")
    for j in range(5):
        print("\t" + str(values[i][j]), end=" ")

main()
```

This code should've printed a 5 x 5 matrix with a range of 1-25 without repeating the number. For some reason, the if command I did put in did not randomize it. Can someone help me with the solution?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Remember this is an **interactive** community. You are seeking an answer. Interact with the community so they can tell if your question has been answered. If an answer meets your needs accept the answer. That is how the community knows your question has been answered. If your question has not been answered add comments to the proposed answer. Possibly clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from random import shuffle

numbers = list(range(1, 26))
shuffle(numbers)
values = [[numbers[i * 5 + j] for j in range(5)] for i in range(5)]
```

First you create a list of numbers from 1 to 25. Then you randomly shuffle it. And finally you create a matrix out of it.

Answer (score 1):

The original code shows an attempt to make sure a value is used only once.

```
if values[r][c] != rand:
            values[r][c] = rand
```

However, the code checks a specific value at `values[r][c]` which is the initial value of `0`. So, `rand` is assigned to that location. This does not prevent the same `rand` value from being generated and assigned later to another location (i.e., a duplicate).

```
import random


def main():
    values = [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]
    used_numbers = [] # store used numbers.
    for r in range(5):
        for c in range(5):
            rand = random.randint(1, 25)
            while rand in used_numbers: # True if rand has been used
                # rand has been used
                # generate numbers until an unused number is found
                rand = random.randint(1, 25)
            values[r][c] = rand # assign the number to values[r][c]
            used_numbers.append(rand) # add the number to the list of used
            # numbers.

    for i in range(5):
        print("\n")
        for j in range(5):
            print("\t" + str(values[i][j]), end=" ")


main()
```

Test results:

```
    14  16  25  22  19 

    15  10  18  7   2 

    13  8   20  6   5 

    24  17  9   1   12 

    11  23  4   3   21
```